# XML Serialize and Deserialize Problem XML Structure

Tags: web-services, xml-serialization, c#-4.0, xml-deserialization

Camarades,

I'm having the following problem. Caught a list Struct, Serialize (Valid W3C) and send to a WebService. In the WebService I receive, transform to a string, valid by the W3C and then Deserializer, but when I try to run it, always occurs error, saying that some objects were not closed.

Any help?

Sent Code:

```
#region ListToXML
    private XmlDocument ListToXMLDocument(object __Lista)
    {
        XmlDocument _ListToXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            XmlDocument _XMLDoc      = new XmlDocument();
            MemoryStream _StreamMem  = new MemoryStream();
            XmlSerializer _XMLSerial = new XmlSerializer(__Lista.GetType());

            StreamWriter _StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(_StreamMem, Encoding.UTF8);
            _XMLSerial.Serialize(_StreamWriter, __Lista);

            _StreamMem.Position = 0;
            _XMLDoc.Load(_StreamMem);
            if (_XMLDoc.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                _ListToXMLDocument = _XMLDoc;
        }
        catch (Exception __Excp)
        {
            new uException(__Excp).GerarLogErro(CtNomeBiblioteca);
        }

        return _ListToXMLDocument;
    }
    #endregion
```

Receive Code:

```
    #region XMLDocumentToTypedList
    private List<T> XMLDocumentToTypedList<T>(string __XMLDocument)
    {
        List<T> _XMLDocumentToTypedList = new List<T>();

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer _XMLSerial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
            MemoryStream _MemStream  = new MemoryStream();

            StreamWriter _StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(_MemStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            _StreamWriter.Write(__XMLDocument);

            _MemStream.Position = 0;
            _XMLDocumentToTypedList = (List<T>)_XMLSerial.Deserialize(_MemStream);
            return _XMLDocumentToTypedList;
        }
        catch (Exception _Ex)
        {
            new uException(_Ex).GerarLogErro(CtNomeBiblioteca);
            throw _Ex;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: If you call these methods together in sequence do they work?  (That is, are you positive that these two methoods hold the problem, and not the web service call?)

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I managed to solve the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much effort, and to examine some code from the internet, I managed to solve the problem.
I do not know what reason, however, know that this way works. Below the code.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(__XMLDocument);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);

XmlSerializer _XMLSerial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<tinfCte>));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString()));

stream.Position = 0;
_XMLDocumentToTInfCTeList = (List<tinfCte>)_XMLSerial.Deserialize(stream);
return _XMLDocumentToTInfCTeList;
```